# Xamarin Android: Downloading file using DownloadManager is much faster then using .NET DownloadFileAsync

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am developing a xamarin app for android that downloads a large file (500 MB) from a local server over a WiFi. 
Initially, i used the DownloadFileAsync API in .NET to download the file. I get a download speed of approx. 1 MBPS. 
The same file, when I download using the built-in Android DownloadManager (Context.DownloadService API), i clock speed of 3.5+ MPBS.

Is it due to some limitation with Monodroid runtime that Xamarin uses to run apps or Android in general favors DownloadManager?

Comment: Native is faster than the mono implementation. This was the whole reasoning for making this library: https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient.

Comment: Yes valdetero, you seem to be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this from support@xamarin.com:

The native implementation will ALWAYS be faster, and thus why the magnificent Paul Betts created ModernHttpClient: https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient

There's also a great guide by our own Rob Gibbens about these libraries: http://arteksoftware.com/resilient-network-services-with-xamarin/

Your observation is close, but it's mainly that the native functionality should perform better than some of the classes that sit ontop of them.

I hope this helps!